# How to invalidate() on return from a dialog?

Tags: android, invalidation

I have a drawing canvas with an `OnTouchListener` from which I call an `AlertDialog`.

In the dialog I reset the underlying data for the canvas (or not depending on user). On returning to the canvas with `dialog.cancel()` the canvas does not redraw and I want it to.
This means the user has to click on the canvas to cause it to redraw - not good!

Because the dialog runs asynchronously any call to `invalidate()` in the canvas is completed before the dialog returns the changed underlying data. Any attempt I make to invalidate or reference the canvas from inside the dialog buttons code results in errors. I seem to be in catch 22!

Can enyone give me advice?

dialog code:

```
case DIALOG_NEW_ID:
    AlertDialog.Builder builder5 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder5.setMessage("     WARNING" +
            "\nYour current game will be lost")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                   
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    })              
    .setNegativeButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            cells.reset();
            gameMode = 0;
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert5 = builder5.create();             
    alert5.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() { 
        public void onDismiss( DialogInterface dialog) { 
            Log.d(TAG, "Dialog cancelled");// debug log entry 
            //myBoard.invalidate();
        }
    });     
    dialog = alert5;                
    break;
```

Dialog calling code `onTouch` in the canvas:

```
    case MODE_SOLUTION:
        break;
    default:                            
        showDialog(DIALOG_NEW_ID);
        invalidate();
}// end switch
```

The Main Class set up:

```
public class SudokuGame extends Activity {
static final int DIALOG_OPEN_ID = 0;
static final int DIALOG_INFO_ID = 1;
static final int DIALOG_FAIL_ID = 2;
static final int DIALOG_SAVE_ID = 3;
static final int DIALOG_NEW_ID = 4;
static final int MODE_ENTRY = 0;
static final int MODE_PLAY = 1;
static final int MODE_SHOW_ERRORS = 3;
static final int MODE_SOLUTION = 4;
final String TAG = "Game";
int  gameMode;
SKU cells;
View myBoard;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
    View myBoard = new NewBoard(this);        
    setContentView(myBoard);
    setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    showDialog(DIALOG_OPEN_ID);        
}// end onCreate

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
```

The Class NewBoard which is nested in the main class:

```
    class NewBoard extends View implements OnTouchListener{
    int cW;  // canvas width
    int cH;  // canvas height
    int cellSize,textSize;
    int boardX,boardY;  
    int runner, tX, tY,pX,pY,selectorX,selectorY;
    int gap ;
    int btn1X,btn1Y, selected;
    int infoButtonX, infoButtonY,quitButtonX,quitButtonY;
    boolean btn1Pressed, btn2Pressed,  btn3Pressed, btn4Pressed, btn5Pressed;
    String btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5;

    public NewBoard(Context context){ // NewBoard Constructor
        super(context);
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);  
        cells = new SKU();
        readStateStore();
    }// end NewBoard Constructor

    @Override 
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = new Paint();  
        Rect textRect = new Rect();
```

Comment: `Any attempt I make to invalidate or reference the canvas from inside the dialog buttons code results in errors` - may help to show us this code and the resulting errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibilities:

- make the dialog non-cancelable
- set an OnCancelListener for the dialog that will then call invalidate().

Comment: Tried adding the OnDismissListener and it has not solved the problem. The code put in onDismiss i.e. invalidate(), behaves exactly like putting the code inside the dialog buttons. i.e. the original problem. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I'm a little vague on exactly what the problem is. Are you getting errors from invalidating the canvas from a different thread, or is it that the canvas is being invalidated before the data returned from the dialog can be processed? I agree with @Bert and @ice911 -- you need to post more details.

Comment: Yes, I am unused to the help forum and new to Android. I have added some code to the question. My problem is that the line "cells.reset();" changes the arrays from which the canvas is drawn. When the dialog closes and shows the canvas again it has not been redrawn so shows the old array values. The "invalidate()" in the dialog calling code was executed long before the user chooses and closed the dialog because the dialog runs asynchronously, so the canvas is sat waiting for a touch before it redraws.I have no threads other than the main one. I want some means to tell the canvas to redraw.

Comment: Well, I see where you set an OnDismissListener, but did you try adding an OnCancelListener? The onCancel() method can call invalidate().

Comment: I have changed the OnDismissListener for OnCancelListener and it behaves just the same. The logCat entry for line "Log.d(TAG, "Dialog cancelled")" works ok and the exception is thrown the "myBoard.invalidate()" line is executed. Is all this because I am trying to invalidate a canvas that is not in focus because the dialog is in focus?

Comment: If you're getting a null pointer exception, then myBoard hasn't been initialized. It has nothing to do with asynchronous threads or focus.

Comment: Doesn't the line "View myBoard = new NewBoard(this);" in the onCreate routine initialise myBoard?

Comment: It initializes a local variable in the onCreate method. If you also have an instance variable declared in the class, then the `View` declaration in onCreate is masking the field. just say `myBoard = new NewBoard(this);` and the instance variable, instead of a local variable, will be initialized.

Comment: You are right! The variable myBoard in the onCreate method is not the same variable as the myBoard declared at the start of the class. I can see this definately now. Many thanks to you Ted. Unfortunately I am still at a loss as to how to make the call for invalidate() to the right place.

Answer (score 2):

Could you post some code of your situation with the dialog box and invalidate(), and the error message being returned back?

I don't see why you couldn't do the following (dialog box that invalidates a mapView):

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builderAccountInfo = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builderAccountInfo.setMessage("TEST")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setTitle("TEST")
        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            changeUserCanvas();
            mapView.invalidate();
            dialog.cancel();
       }
   });
        AlertDialog alertAccountInfo = builderAccountInfo.create();

        alertAccountInfo.show();
```

The error would probably come from the context you're using to invalidate, but more information on the changes to the canvas you're making and your dialog box code is needed.

////////////////////////////////Edit

it looks like there is a problem between the local and global variable of View myBoard.

```
public class SudokuGame extends Activity {
static final int DIALOG_OPEN_ID = 0;
static final int DIALOG_INFO_ID = 1;
static final int DIALOG_FAIL_ID = 2;
static final int DIALOG_SAVE_ID = 3;
static final int DIALOG_NEW_ID = 4;
static final int MODE_ENTRY = 0;
static final int MODE_PLAY = 1;
static final int MODE_SHOW_ERRORS = 3;
static final int MODE_SOLUTION = 4;
final String TAG = "Game";
int  gameMode;
SKU cells;
View myBoard;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
    View myBoard = new NewBoard(this);        
    setContentView(myBoard);
    setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    showDialog(DIALOG_OPEN_ID);        
}// end onCreate
```

View myBoard in onCreate is initialized locally, but the global View myBoard has not been initialized because of the local scope. You have two myBoard variables and only one is initialized. To fix this quickly, I would change:

```
View myBoard = new NewBoard(this);
```

to

```
myBoard = new NewBoard(this);
```

Comment: Your line "mapView.invalidate(); " is very much the code I have been trying. It compiles but fails at runtime with a nullPointerException. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, your error is coming from myBoard.invalidate(); so we need more code to step through where it could possibly be null.

Comment: invalidate() will tell the canvas to refresh, but you need to make sure you have the correct Canvas object which is also initialized. This function should be called after the option to do this has been selected from the alert dialog. This would be the elegant way of handling changes after a user's decision from a dialog box. myBoard seems to be flawed in some way, so you need to search down that path to find out why it is null.

Comment: Check out my edit above and let me know if that was helpful or not.