# invalidate() does not changes content of custom view immediately

Tags: android, canvas, dialog, invalidation, custom-view

I have a xml layout that contains a custom view:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="50" 
    >
        <org.example.sudoku.PuzzleView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/puzzlebackground"
            android:id="@+id/puzzleId"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I have a activity that set this layout as its content, calls a Dialog for user input, which in turn calls a function in PuzzleView to eventually change the content of the PuzzleView. The problem is that, the change has not been redrawn right after the Dialog dismiss. Instead, it is redrawn on the next other input from user.
Here are some snippet of code that may help you:

Game.java:

```
// ...
public void showKeypadOrError(int x, int y)
{
    int tiles[] = getUsedTiles(x,y);
    if (tiles.length == 9)
    {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_moves_label, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    }else
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "showKeypad: used=" + toPuzzleString(tiles));
        Dialog v = new Keypad(this, this.puzzleView, x, y);
        v.show();
    }
}
public void setTile(int x, int y, int value) {
    puzzle[y * 9 + x] = value;
}
```

Keypad.java:

```
private void setListeners()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
    {
        final int t = i + 1;
        keys[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                returnResult(t);
            }
        });
    }
}

private void returnResult(int tile)
{   
    puzzleView.setSelectedTile(selX, selY, tile);
    puzzleView.invalidate();
    dismiss();
}
```

And finally, PuzzleView.java

```
public void setSelectedTile(int X, int Y, int tile) {
    game.setTile(X, Y, tile);
    //this.invalidate();// may change hints
}
```

I have found a question that seems similar to my problem but I couldn't figure out what is the solution:

[How to invalidate() on return from a dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888481/how-to-invalidate-on-return-from-a-dialog)

Thank you very much for all your help!
Edit: add more code - hope this help:
PuzzleView.java

```
// Handle input in touch mode
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    // Allow player to choose the tile that defined by game
    // But only allow the user to modify the tiles that are blank
    select((int) (event.getX() / width),
            (int) (event.getY() / height));

    int[] predefined = new int[81];
    // Get the tile that are not blank (predefined by game)
    predefined = game.getPredefinedTileFromPuzzle();
    // Check if the selected tile is whether predefined or not
    if (predefined[selY * 9 + selX] == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    //Call the Dialog input from Game.java
    game.showKeypadOrError(selX, selY);
    Log.i(TAG, "Right before terminate onTouchEvent()");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Just for the sake of testing, do `returnResult(4)` somewhere else other than clicklistener... hardcode the tile value and see if invalidate happens...

Answer (score 1):

You should invalidate after the dialog is dismissed.

Implement the `DialogInterface.OnDismissListener` interface and invalidate in `OnDismiss` callback.

```
    Dialog v = new Keypad(this, this.puzzleView, x, y);

    v.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
        public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface arg0) {
            puzzleView.postInvalidate ();
        }
    });

     v.show();
```

Comment: Could you explain more please? I try to do as you said but it doesn't work. Where should I implement DialogInterface.OnDismissListener ?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, I have just added more code of PuzzleView.java (Override the onTouchEvent). Does it help you?

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work. I think the invalidate() should work in setSelectedTile function in PuzzleView.java as this change the content of the puzzle. I comment out because I dont' know why it failed to work.

Comment: UI is not updated? then in place of `puzzleView.invalidate();` do `puzzleView.requestLayout();`

Comment: It still doesn't work. Could you explain why the this.invalidate() in function of setSelectedTile() in PuzzleView.java doesn't work? The function game.setTile(X, Y, tile) has already changed the selected tile to the number which user chose.

Comment: You can remove the onTouch code and add the keypad code in ur post

Comment: I have edit the question to add code for setTile() in Game.java .

Comment: When user touch a tile (a sudoku puzzle have 81 tiles), onTouchEvent call game.showKeypadOrError() but I notice that before game.showKeyPadOrError() finishes (change the tile and dismiss the dialog), the onTouchEvent() has already invalidate() and terminate. That's why any change in View only updated in the next touch event.

Comment: You can try `puzzleView.postInvalidate()` in `setTileSelected()`

Comment: After hard time try to solve the problem, it seems that there's still no suitable solution. Anyway, thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

just do `puzzleView.requestLayout();`